# How can I ssh to vm from mac under vpn

Tags: ssh, vpn, virtual-machines

I have a vmware fusion which is installed a rhel in it, I can ssh to the rhel from my mac. But when I enabled VPN on mac, I can not ssh to rhel anymore. Details are as below:

I tried Reverse SSH Tunnel(http://toic.org/blog/2009/reverse-ssh-port-forwarding/#.U4AOB5SSzjI):

- ## 1. in vm (rhel terminal): ssh -R 2210:localhost:22 192.168.1.104 -v

  (it exited with the msg "Unauthorized use prohibited.").
- ## 2. in mac: ssh -p 2210 localhos

The above works.

Then I turned on vpn on mac:

- ## 1. in vm (rhel terminal): ssh -R 2210:localhost:22 192.168.1.104 -v    (it exited with the msg "Unauthorized use prohibited.").
- ## 2. in mac: connect vpn.
- ## 3. in mac: ssh -p 2210 localhost.

It failed. "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host"

Anyone can help me with the issue? It's weird because it worked via the above steps with mac 10.7, after I upgraded OS to 10.9, it failed..

Answer (score 0):

I assume you connect to a vpn server different to your vm?

Maybe you route all traffic from your mac through your vpn.
So your local net isn't accessable anymore.
If so, you could try to uncomment the redirect gateway clientside:

```
#redirect-gateway def1
```

Comment: VPN server is hosted by company, vm is installed on my local mac.

Comment: VPN is hosted by company, vm is installed on my local MAC. I'm using Cisco AnyConnect security mobility client to connect remote vpn server, any hints of how can I comment out this line?